# Permisos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes,

Estoy configurando MySQL en un servidor por directAdmin. Mi problema radica en que creo un usuario y quiero que el mismo vea solamente 5 tablas de N que tiene la base de datos.

Si alguien me podria brindar una solución seria de gran ayuda.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Saludos.

Comment: es hosting o server propio

Comment: Ese manager que estas usando, pregunta,¿ te permite ejecutar .sql?

Answer (score 0):

Luego que crees el usuario dale los siguientes privilegios(asumiendo que el usuario esta creado para localhost y para 192.168.x.x)

```
GRANT SELECT ON basededatos.tabla TO usuario@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'clave';
GRANT SELECT ON basededatos.tabla TO usuario@192.168.x.x IDENTIFIED BY 'clave';
```

Comment: Ya intente hacer eso pero sigo podiendo ver toda la tabla con el nuevo usuario.